# Are there any polyfills for display: table, table-row, table-cell etc

Tags: css, tablerow, css-tables, polyfills

I'm realizing that, for a lot of purposes, display: table and likewise table-row, table-cell and so forth have very useful positioning properties, and can be used instead of floats for a lot of purposes, such as for making floatless menus, and better aligned footers. However, the lack of support is a real deterrent.

I'd like to know what options are there for polyfills to emulate display: table, table-cell, table-row etc?

Answer (score 5):

The support for `table-row`, for instance, is actually pretty good. It's been in IE since version 8: http://caniuse.com/#search=table-row.

If you're looking for a shim to patch it in IE6 and 7, you might find what you're looking for in [display-table.htc](http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/), which is designed specifically for IE6/7.