# Table-cell in IE6/IE7 without javascript

Tags: html, css

Following the code:

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 300px; background: lightblue;">
<div style="display: table-cell; width: 30px; background: lightcoral;">A</div>
<div style="display: table-cell; background: wheat;">B</div>
</div>
```

How to make it work with only css in IE6/IE7?

Comment: It's likely that it's not possible. If it *were* possible, people would be using the CSS-only solution in the first place, instead of JavaScript-based and other workarounds. That said - 1) what are you trying to achieve here, are you sure using a `<table>` element isn't the much saner way to go? 2) are you sure you need to care about IE6? Why? That should no longer be necessary except in some very, very esoteric edge cases.

Comment: What is the best approach with javascript vanilla? I need IE6 support, I am forced :(

Comment: This answer could do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365646/are-there-any-polyfills-for-display-table-table-row-table-cell-etc

Comment: In an edge case like this, I would just use a `<table>`. Problem solved. The JavaScript you will have to use to work around this is going to be much more of a negative than the loss of semantic correctness.